Pass column name as parameter in Oracle DB function
I have a problem related with Oracle DB function. I don;t know how to pass column_name as parameter. Below I present current function without parameters and it's working fine:
At the beginning i'm creating two types:
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TYPE metric_record AS OBJECT (
    period_start VARCHAR2(255),
    data_01_avg NUMBER,
    data_02_avg NUMBER,
    data_03_avg NUMBER,
    data_04_avg NUMBER,
    group_name VARCHAR2(255)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TYPE metric_table AS TABLE OF metric_record;

And the function:
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION get_metrics_summary RETURN metric_table IS
    s_metrics metric_table;
BEGIN
    SELECT metric_record(
        TO_CHAR(period_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
        AVG(data_01_avg),
        AVG(data_02_avg),
        AVG(data_03_avg),
        AVG(data_04_avg),
        group_name)
    BULK COLLECT INTO s_metrics
    FROM (
        SELECT
            TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS') AS period_start,
            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS time_start,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_01),9) AS data_01_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_02),2) AS data_02_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_03),9) AS data_03_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_04),2) AS data_04_avg,
            m.HARDCODED_COLUMN_NAME AS group_name
        FROM METRICS t
        INNER JOIN METADATA m ON t.metadata_id = m.id
        WHERE m.HARDCODED_COLUMN_NAME = 2
        GROUP BY TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS'),
                TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96,
                m.HARDCODED_COLUMN_NAME
    )
    GROUP BY period_start, group_name
    ORDER BY period_start;

    RETURN s_metrics;
END get_metrics_summary;

above function is working fine, but as You can see I have hardcoded column. I wan't to pass 'HARDCODED_COLUMN_NAME' as parameter, like this:
...get_metrics_summary(COL_NAME)...
and then use it in my query in each place where I need it (3 places):
...m.COL_NAME AS group_name...
...m.COL_NAME = 2...
...m.COL_NAME...
Beside of that as You can see I have hardcoded value for my column, but as column name it should be passed as parameter:
...m.COL_NAME = VALUE...
...get_metrics_summary(COL_NAME, VALUE)...
I was trying for some time how to figure it out but I don't know how, please help :)
I'm expecting updated, fixed, working, rebuilded query or different solution how can I retrieve my data. Additional info: i'll make a call to trigger this function and retrieve data from my app.
I was trying to find on stack overflow and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but was not working.
I have implemented EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION function1 RETURN metric_table IS
    v_sql VARCHAR2(8000);
    s_metrics metric_table;
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'SELECT metric_record(
        TO_CHAR(period_start, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''),
        AVG(data_01_avg),
        AVG(data_02_avg),
        AVG(data_03_avg),
        AVG(data_04_avg),
        group_name)
    BULK COLLECT INTO s_metrics
    FROM (
        SELECT
            TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, ''SSSSS''))/900)*900, ''SSSSS'') AS period_start,
            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, ''SSSSS''))/900)/96, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') AS time_start,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_01),9) AS data_01_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_02),2) AS data_02_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_03),9) AS data_03_avg,
            ROUND(AVG(t.data_04),2) AS data_04_avg,
            t.METADATA_ID AS group_name
        FROM METRICS t
        GROUP BY TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, ''SSSSS''))/900)*900, ''SSSSS''),
                TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, ''SSSSS''))/900)/96,
                t.METADATA_ID
    )
    GROUP BY period_start, group_name
    ORDER BY period_start';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO s_metrics;
    RETURN s_metrics;
END function1;

but now I have an error
select * from table(function1());
select function1() from dual;

ORA-03001: niezaimplementowana funkcja (unimplemented function)
ORA-06512: przy "SYSTEM.FUNCTION1", linia 30 (by "SYSTEM.FUNCTION1", line 30)
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.



Provide the DDL of table METRICS.

metric_record is not a "record", it is an object data-type. A RECORD data-type is a PL/SQL data-type - you can use your naming convention if you want but it does not match the actual type and may cause confusion for later developers if they see a "record" type that is not actually a RECORD.

Thank you for check and explanation, it will be improved on my site with proper naming convention.

Do not use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, instead whitelist the possible values in a CASE expression:
CREATE NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION get_metrics_summary(
  i_col_name IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN metric_table
IS
  s_metrics metric_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT metric_record(
           TO_CHAR(period_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
           AVG(data_01_avg),
           AVG(data_02_avg),
           AVG(data_03_avg),
           AVG(data_04_avg),
           group_name
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO s_metrics
  FROM (
    SELECT TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS') AS period_start,
           TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS time_start,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_01),9) AS data_01_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_02),2) AS data_02_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_03),9) AS data_03_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_04),2) AS data_04_avg,
           CASE i_col_name
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END AS group_name
    FROM   METRICS t
           INNER JOIN METADATA m
           ON t.metadata_id = m.id
    WHERE  CASE i_col_name
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END = 2
    GROUP BY
           TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS'),
           TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96,
           CASE i_col_name
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END
  )
  GROUP BY period_start, group_name
  ORDER BY period_start;

  RETURN s_metrics;
END get_metrics_summary;


For passing multiple key-value pairs to the function, something like:
CREATE NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION get_metrics_summary(
  i_col_name1 IN VARCHAR2,
  i_value1    IN VARCAHR2,
  i_col_name2 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  i_value2    IN VARCAHR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  i_col_name3 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  i_value3    IN VARCAHR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURN metric_table
IS
  s_metrics metric_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT metric_record(
           TO_CHAR(period_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
           AVG(data_01_avg),
           AVG(data_02_avg),
           AVG(data_03_avg),
           AVG(data_04_avg),
           group_name
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO s_metrics
  FROM (
    SELECT TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS') AS period_start,
           TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS time_start,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_01),9) AS data_01_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_02),2) AS data_02_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_03),9) AS data_03_avg,
           ROUND(AVG(t.data_04),2) AS data_04_avg,
           CASE i_col_name1
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END AS group_name
    FROM   METRICS t
           INNER JOIN METADATA m
           ON t.metadata_id = m.id
    WHERE  CASE 
           WHEN i_col_name1 = 'COLUMN1' AND m.column1 = i_value1 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name1 = 'COLUMN2' AND m.column2 = i_value1 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name1 = 'COLUMN3' AND m.column3 = i_value1 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name1 = 'COLUMN4' AND m.column4 = i_value1 THEN 1
           -- No default, expect the 1st key-value pair to always be present
           END = 1
    AND    CASE 
           WHEN i_col_name2 = 'COLUMN1' AND m.column1 = i_value2 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name2 = 'COLUMN2' AND m.column2 = i_value2 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name2 = 'COLUMN3' AND m.column3 = i_value2 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name2 = 'COLUMN4' AND m.column4 = i_value2 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name2 IS NULL THEN 1 -- Always match if not set
           END = 1
    AND    CASE 
           WHEN i_col_name3 = 'COLUMN1' AND m.column1 = i_value3 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name3 = 'COLUMN2' AND m.column2 = i_value3 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name3 = 'COLUMN3' AND m.column3 = i_value3 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name3 = 'COLUMN4' AND m.column4 = i_value3 THEN 1
           WHEN i_col_name3 IS NULL THEN 1 -- Always match if not set
           END = 1
    GROUP BY
           TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS'),
           TRUNC(t.TIMESTAMP) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t.TIMESTAMP, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96,
           CASE i_col_name1
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END,
           CASE i_col_name2
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END,
           CASE i_col_name3
           WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN m.column1
           WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN m.column2
           WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN m.column3
           WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN m.column4
           END
  )
  GROUP BY period_start, group_name
  ORDER BY period_start;

  RETURN s_metrics;
END get_metrics_summary;


Thank You, it's working fine :)
One more thing. I was trying to use EXECUTE INTERMEDIATE to have opportunity to concatenate STRING as sql query, but to the point:
    ```

WHERE
CASE column_name
WHEN 'COLUMN_X' THEN m.COLUMN_X
END = 1
I can have up to 20 where criteria:
where col_01 = a and col_02 = b etc

How to pass someting like array to function and make a loop... is that even possible?

@Bartek I'm not sure I fully understand what you want but maybe CASE WHEN i_col_name = 'COLUMN1' AND m.column1 = 'a' THEN 1 WHEN i_col_name = 'COLUMN2' AND m.column2 = 'b' THEN 1 END = 1.

@MTO
Solution that You provide i's working fine. I need to extend it.
WHERE              CASE column_name             WHEN 'AREA' THEN m.AREA             END = 1
Is working.
I need to extend function to have a couple of where criteria, for example:
function_name(column_names[], values[])
`SOME KIND OF LOOP
WHERE column_names[0] = values[0] AND column_names[1] = values[1] AND column_names[x] = values[x]

@Bartek Updated - SQL does not (easily) support using collections dynamically in SQL statements, instead you could have the maximum number of arguments in the function signature and pass the filters you need and let the others default to NULL and the use CASE expressions to filter in your query.

Dynamic SQL it is (so yes - you'll need execute immediate).
This is a simplified example; code is based on Scott's sample schema and its emp table. Function returns number of rows whose column - passed as a parameter - has values greater than 20.
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_column in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_str  varchar2(500);
  5    retval number;
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select count(*) from emp ' ||
  8             'where ' || par_column || ' > 20';
  9    execute immediate l_str into retval;
 10
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

Testing:
SQL> select f_test('deptno') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPTNO')
----------------
               6

SQL> select f_test('sal') from dual;

F_TEST('SAL')
-------------
           14

Beware of SQL injection. Read about dbms_assert package.

On the other hand, maybe you'd rather avoid dynamic SQL. It is difficult to properly write, debug and maintain. Generally speaking, you should first verify whether it is correctly written by displaying statement you're about to execute. People sometimes hope that code they write is OK, but sometimes (often?) is not because of various (syntax) errors.
So: how about a different approach, which doesn't look wow, but is simple and works just fine - switch to IF-THEN-ELSE:
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_column in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_str  varchar2(500);
  5    retval number;
  6  begin
  7    if par_column = 'deptno' then
  8       select count(*) into retval
  9       from emp
 10       where deptno > 20;
 11    elsif par_column = 'sal' then
 12       select count(*) into retval
 13       from emp
 14       where sal > 20;
 15    end if;
 16
 17    return retval;
 18  end;
 19  /

Function created.

Testing:
SQL> select f_test('deptno') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPTNO')
----------------
               6

SQL> select f_test('sal') from dual;

F_TEST('SAL')
-------------
           14

SQL>


Thank you for quick response I have answered by editing my post. Please check
